# Hbase: HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation Fatal Error

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am attempting to get an `HTable` from an `HTablePool`, but I get this error.  Can someone help me understand what this means and how to go about troubleshooting and fixing it?

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Unexpected exception during initialization, aborting
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/master
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1021)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:171)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.watchAndCheckExists(ZKUtil.java:226)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperNodeTracker.start(ZooKeeperNodeTracker.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:581)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:570)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTableFactory.createHTableInterface(HTableFactory.java:36)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.createHTable(HTablePool.java:268)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.findOrCreateTable(HTablePool.java:198)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.getTable(HTablePool.java:173)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool.getTable(HTablePool.java:216)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```